# How to input the euro symbol here?

Tags: support

I was trying to edit this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320039/coin-flip-starts-with-different-amount-of-money).  I was having trouble understanding the question at first glance, got confused because I was expected some monentary value.  Yes I do understand it doesn't really change the mathematics of the question; however, it is what one expect to see when doing these problems.

I tried to put in $\euro$ however, it did not render.  Thus the reason for this post, as the title states.

Answer (score 4):

Though it's not ideal, you can just put the Unicode euro symbol in a piece of MathJax and it will come out okay: for example,

> `$€100 \times 2$`

produces

> $€100 \times 2$

Looking at the advice given on the [TeX.SE thread about the euro symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/latest-advice-on-the-euro-symbol), it seems that a "proper" solution would require loading esoteric packages that aren't available automatically in MathJax. Whether or not there's a way of *making* MathJax load those packages, I don't know.

Comment: guess, will just have to keep with gold coins instead of the euro.

Answer (score 4):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a good site to find unknown LaTeX characters.

It finds `\EURdig` `\EUR` `\texteuro` `\EURtm` and `\EURhv`, none of which are recognized by MathJax. So it seems that we need to resort to using `\unicode{0x20AC}`: $\unicode{0x20AC}$